# How can I use pipe operator (|) in gvim cabbrev in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to create an alias for two commands together - `:tabnew and :E` on gvim command prompt. And, I want to add that as a shortcut in .vimrc.

I tried `cabbrev t tabnew | E` but it doesn't work. Is it possible to use `|` in cabbrev?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:cabbr t tabnew \| :Explore
```